# Is there any good usage example for “Did I tell you”?

Tags: questions, past-tense

As far as I can tell, rephrasing Wikipedia, Simple Past draws attention to actual occurrence of the past action or event, as opposed to its present consequences. (See [Present perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_perfect)).

Doesn't asking someone a question usually imply some consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. An man and wife are talking and the man says:
"Did I tell you about the time I ate ten hamburgers?"
The wife sighs and says "Yes honey, you've told me that story a hundred times!"
(This sounds better with "Have I told you […]?" instead of "Did I tell you […]?")

or

A man says to his wife "Did I tell you to turn the oven off before we left?" "Did I tell you […]?" is requesting a response.

Comment: But aren't those questions of yours imply consequences? "Did I tell you about the time I ate ten hamburgers?" (If not, I'm gonna tell you that story). "Did I tell you to turn the oven off before we left?" (If not, I'm gonna ask you if you've done it, we can even return to turn it off).

Comment: I might assume though, that it's not that there is no consequences, but the emphasis is on whether event has occured or not.

Comment: Also, if "Did I tell you […]?" is requesting a response, what is "Have I told you […]?" then?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example from my own life. My wife and I work near each other and share a car. We have about a half hour ride home at the end of the day and we will have a conversation. Being that my attention is divided, I might not remember if I shared a certain detail of my day, or if I asked a particular question I intended to ask. I would then say "Did I tell you […]?" or "Did I ask you […]?"